# Can i get Soundcloud user listening history?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, soundcloud

i can't get users (me) listening history on SoundCloud, i tried :

- SoundCloud API, didn't find a request to do that
- FB API (music.listens), works with deezer/spotify but not SoundCloud

So is there a way to retrieve SoundCloud user listening history ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately we do not offer an API to get listetning history.

Comment: Is this something that you would be interested in providing in the future? I use Spotify and iTunes specifically for the Scrobbling features of Last.FM, and really want to be able to track my listens via Soundcloud because so many of my favorite, more obscure artists publish tracks and sets through Soundcloud. Would it be against TOS somehow to hijack my own play clicks and get the metadata through the API?

Comment: @daekano there are chrome and firefox extensions for this purpose – google "soundcloud last fm scrobbler", I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would indeed be great to know what a user has listened to (e.g. to predict what a user might like) or even just what a user is currently playing. Is that something we can expect to see in the future?

Comment: Up: does it is still the same ?